# how to give the url in joomla supporting form

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I’m new to joomla and I’m using joomla 2.5. I need to redirect the page in joomla to another page. I saw that JROUTE is used for giving urls in joomla. but it start only from joomla folder. I need to get a file in the path

```
http://localhost/joomla/images/uploads/file.pdf
```

how can I write the above URL in joomla standard format?? can I use `JURI base` with `jroute` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
echo JURI::root().'images/uploads/file.pdf'
```

JURI::root() will return the site url.
If you required physical path try `JPATH_SITE`

Hope it helps..